# Exporting image element to word document using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to export Html div element to word file using JavaScript. The div element contains some texts and two images. One image is using the absolute path and the other image is using base64 image path. When I export the html div, it only exports the image with absolute path.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function Export2Doc(element, filename = '') {

            var preHtml = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML To Doc</title></head><body>";
            var postHtml = "</body></html>";

            var html = preHtml + document.getElementById(element).innerHTML + postHtml;

            var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
                type: 'application/msword'
            });

            var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html);


            filename = filename ? filename + '.doc' : 'document.doc';


            var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

            if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
            } else {

                downloadLink.href = url;
                downloadLink.download = filename;
                downloadLink.click();
            }

            document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
        }

</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="exportContent">
            <h2> What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

           <br/>
   <img src="https://3bbdb23jem2j4esrdm1gcdbd-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/Limanew.jpg" alt="Computer Man" height="400" width="400" >
            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
   <br />
            Test
        </div>

        <button onclick="Export2Doc('exportContent');">Export as .doc</button>
        
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the messy code, first time using snippets. It is possible. Copy the code and past it in notepad and save it as AnyName.html, run it will will work perfectly.

```js
   
function Export2Doc(element, filename = '') {
            //  _html_ will be replace with custom html
            var meta= "Mime-Version: 1.0\nContent-Base: " + location.href + "\nContent-Type: Multipart/related; boundary=\"NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY\";type=\"text/html\"\n\n--NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\nContent-Location: " + location.href + "\n\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n_html_</html>";
            //  _styles_ will be replaced with custome css
            var head= "<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\n<style>\n_styles_\n</style>\n</head>\n";
  
            var html = document.getElementById(element).innerHTML ;
            
            var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
                type: 'application/msword'
            });
            
            var  css = (
                   '<style>' +
                   'img {width:300px;}table {border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;}td{padding: 6px;}' +
                   '</style>'
                  );
//  Image Area %%%%
            var options = { maxWidth: 624};
            var images = Array();
            var img = $("#"+element).find("img");
            for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
                // Calculate dimensions of output image
                var w = Math.min(img[i].width, options.maxWidth);
                var h = img[i].height * (w / img[i].width);
                // Create canvas for converting image to data URL
                var canvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
                canvas.width = w;
                canvas.height = h;
                // Draw image to canvas
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                context.drawImage(img[i], 0, 0, w, h);
                // Get data URL encoding of image
                var uri = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                $(img[i]).attr("src", img[i].src);
                img[i].width = w;
                img[i].height = h;
                // Save encoded image to array
                images[i] = {
                    type: uri.substring(uri.indexOf(":") + 1, uri.indexOf(";")),
                    encoding: uri.substring(uri.indexOf(";") + 1, uri.indexOf(",")),
                    location: $(img[i]).attr("src"),
                    data: uri.substring(uri.indexOf(",") + 1)
                };
            }

            // Prepare bottom of mhtml file with image data
            var imgMetaData = "\n";
            for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                imgMetaData += "--NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY\n";
                imgMetaData += "Content-Location: " + images[i].location + "\n";
                imgMetaData += "Content-Type: " + images[i].type + "\n";
                imgMetaData += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: " + images[i].encoding + "\n\n";
                imgMetaData += images[i].data + "\n\n";
                
            }
            imgMetaData += "--NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY--";
// end Image Area %%

             var output = meta.replace("_html_", head.replace("_styles_", css) +  html) + imgMetaData;

            var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(output);


            filename = filename ? filename + '.doc' : 'document.doc';


            var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

            document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

            if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
            } else {

                downloadLink.href = url;
                downloadLink.download = filename;
                downloadLink.click();
            }

            document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
        }
```

```html
<html><head>
   <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head><body>
 
<div id="exportContent">
            <h2> What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

           <br/>

<img src=" data:image/png;base64,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">
            <br />
            Test
        </div>

        <button onclick="Export2Doc('exportContent');">Export as .doc</button>
        </body></html>
```